# creating a textfile in perl

Tags: perl

I was hoping for some assistance as to how to create a textfile specifically in perl receiving the input from user.

```
print "\ndirectory has been changed";
print "\nDear user, please enter the name of the file you want to create ";

my $nameFile = <>;

open MYFILE, ">$nameFile" or die "couldn't open the file $!";
```

This will create a file although not a text file.

regards
Arian

Comment: Rather than giving your interpretation of the error ("I don't think this is a text file"), you should give the exact indication you have of the error. E.g. "It has an irregular file name" or "When I try to open the file with vim, it cannot find it"

Answer (score 6):

Update: I just realized you did not `chomp` your STDIN there, so you will have a newline attached to the end of your file name.

```
chomp $filename;
```

Should solve that particular hiccup with your file name.

The recommended way to use `open` is using three arguments, and a lexical filehandle. `MYFILE` is a global, with all the inherent drawbacks and benefits.

```
use autodie;  # will check important errors for you, such as open
open my $fh,      '>',               $namefile;
#    ^- lexical   ^- explicit mode   ^- filename separated from mode

print $fh "This is a textfile\n";   # put something in the file
```